# HR doesn't appear unless behind a character

Tags: html

The HR line shows as below (with the period)

```
.<hr style="height:2px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;">
```

where the line on its own does not

```
<hr style="height:2px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;">
```

?

Comment: both work fine!

Comment: one has a '.' in front of it, and that caused the hr to appear.   if no '.', the hr didn't appear.